# Игнорирование определенных URI

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

В конфиге апача есть виртуальный хост

```
<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:80>
     ServerName svn.site.ru
     ServerAlias www.svn.site.ru
     ErrorLog /usr/local/apache/logs/svn.site.ru_error_log
     CustomLog /usr/local/apache/logs/svn.site.ru_access_log common
     ServerAdmin admin@mail.ru
     DocumentRoot /home/usvnuser/public_html/public   
     <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup nobody nobody   
     </IfModule>

  <Directory /home/usvnuser/public_html/public>
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all   </Directory>

  <Location /svn/>
        DAV svn
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion repositories"
        AuthUserFile /home/usvnuser/public_html/files/htpasswd
        AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/usvnuser/public_html/files/authz
        SVNParentPath /home/usvnuser/public_html/files/svn
        SVNPathAuthz Off
        Require valid-user
        SVNListParentPath on   
   </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

В папке `/home/usvnuser/public_html`, которая прописана как `DocumentRoot`, есть файл **.htaccess** следующего содержания:

```
 <Files *.ini> 
 Order Allow,Deny 
 Deny from all 
 </Files>

 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteBase "/"

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] 
 RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

При переходе по URI вида `http://svn.site.ru/svn/test_project/trunk/` мне возвращается ошибка 500. Если же убрать **.htaccess**, то отрывается проект по этому адресу, но перестают работать другие интерфейсы. 
Что нужно прописать в конфигах, чтобы не происходило никакой замены для URI такого вида?

Comment: В конфиге апача строка `LoadModule rewrite_module` раскомментирована?